# unlinkat() a Directory in C

Tags: c, linux, directory, file-descriptor, unlink

I need to  delete a directory in a given path using `unlinkat()`, the program runs fine but it doesn't delete (unlink) the directory (is empty by the way). Using the man7 documentation for `unlinkat()` I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    DIR *dirp;


    if ((dirp = opendir(argv[1]))== NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open the directory %s: %s \n",argv[1],strerror(errno) );
            exit(1);
    }
    unlinkat(dirp,argv[1],AT_REMOVEDIR);


    exit(0);



}
```

The path given in the arguments is relative from the father of the folder I want to erase

Comment: What does `unlinkat` return? What's `errno` after the call?

Comment: You're using the same directory in `opendir()` and `unlinkat()`. So if the `argv[1]` is `foo/bar`, it will try to remove `foo/bar/foo/bar`.

Comment: I changed it in the question, I copied an old piece of code without the unlinkat().@Mat The error says  `Bad file descriptor`

Comment: Pretty sure @Barmar is correct. Try  `unlinkat(dirp,".", AT_REMOVEDIR);`

Comment: No good, keep getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your `dirp` is a pointer to a directory handle (`DIR *`), but the first argument to `unlinkat()` must be a directory descriptor, or `AT_FDCWD` (for "current working directory"). This is clearly stated in the [`unlinkat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlinkat.2.html) man page.

You should always enable compiler warnings (`-Wall` for gcc). It would have pointed you to the problem in this case, too.

To get hold of the underlying descriptor for `dirp`, use [`dirfd(dirp)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dirfd.3.html).

Here is an actual example. It removes the (empty) directories specified in the second and further parameters, relative to the directory/path specified as the first parameter. The directory specified in the first parameter is not removed.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR *dirp;
    int  arg, retval;

    if (argc < 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s BASE-DIRECTORY ITEM-TO-REMOVE ...\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    dirp = opendir(argv[1]);
    if (!dirp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    retval = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    for (arg = 2; arg < argc; arg++) {
        if (unlinkat(dirfd(dirp), argv[arg], AT_REMOVEDIR)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            retval = EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    closedir(dirp);    
    return retval;
}
```